# Confused with logic of login flow in AWS Developer Authenticated Identities

Tags: authentication, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I believe that I have an incorrect flow for implementing Developer Authenticated Identities and I keep hearing and doing different things on the web. So I thought I'd present my entire flow and hear what the correct way of doing this was and present some questions and errors at the bottom.

Initially, I have a user login with a password and username (I'm using nsuserdefaults only temporarily, I will use KeyChain later).

Note: I also have a callback that goes all the way down to see if I properly authenticated a user.

Login Method:

```
-(void)loginBusyTimeUser:(void(^)(BOOL))callBack{
//initialize nsuserdefualts should be keychain later
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

NSMutableDictionary *post = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                      [defaults objectForKey:@"username"], @"username",
                      [defaults objectForKey:@"password"], @"password",
                      nil];
NSError *error;
NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:post options:0 error:&error];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"SOMELOGINURL"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
[[session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    NSDictionary *newJSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                            options:0
                                                              error:&error];
    if(!newJSON || [newJSON objectForKey:@"errorMessage"]){
        NSLog(@"%@",newJSON);
        callBack(false);
        NSLog(@"DID NOT AUTHENTICATE");
    }else{
        NSLog(@"%@",newJSON);
        [defaults setValue:[newJSON objectForKey:@"Token"] forKey:@"Token"];
        [defaults setValue:[newJSON objectForKey:@"IdentityId"] forKey:@"IdentityId"];
        [self authenticateUser:^(BOOL call){
            callBack(call);
        }];
    }
}] resume];
```

}

If Everything is successful, I then authenticate my user with AWS Cognito with the developer authenticated flow:

```
-(void)authenticateUser:(void(^)(BOOL))callBack{
//Now after making sure that your user's credentials are sound, then initialize the IdentityProvider, in this case
//BusytimeAuthenticated
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
id<AWSCognitoIdentityProvider> identityProvider = [[BusytimeAuthenticated alloc] initWithRegionType:AWSRegionUSEast1
                                                                                         identityId:nil
                                                                                     identityPoolId:@"SOMEPOOLID"
                                                                            logins:@{@"cognito-identity.amazonaws.com": [defaults objectForKey:@"Token"]}
                                                                                       providerName:@"cognito-identity.amazonaws.com"
                                                   ];

credentialsProvider = [[AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider alloc] initWithRegionType:AWSRegionUSEast1
                                                               identityProvider:identityProvider
                                                                  unauthRoleArn:nil
                                                                    authRoleArn:nil];
configuration = [[AWSServiceConfiguration alloc] initWithRegion:AWSRegionUSEast1
                                            credentialsProvider:self.credentialsProvider];
AWSServiceManager.defaultServiceManager.defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration;
[[credentialsProvider refresh] continueWithBlock:^id(AWSTask *task){
    if([task isFaulted]){
        callBack(false);
    }else{
    callBack(true);
    }
    return [defaults objectForKey:@"Token"];
}];
```

}

Then the refresh method causes some errors so I'll show my "BusytimeAuthenticated" class (.m)

```
//
//  BusytimeAuthenticated.m
//  BusyTime
//
//  Created by akash kakumani on 10/14/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 BusyTime. All rights reserved.
//

#import "BusytimeAuthenticated.h"

@interface BusytimeAuthenticated()
@property (strong, atomic) NSString *providerName;
@property (strong, atomic) NSString *token;
@end

@implementation BusytimeAuthenticated
@synthesize providerName=_providerName;
@synthesize token=_token;


- (instancetype)initWithRegionType:(AWSRegionType)regionType
                        identityId:(NSString *)identityId
                    identityPoolId:(NSString *)identityPoolId
                            logins:(NSDictionary *)logins
                      providerName:(NSString *)providerName{
    if (self = [super initWithRegionType:regionType identityId:identityId accountId:nil identityPoolId:identityPoolId logins:logins]) {
        self.providerName = providerName;
    }
    return self;
}

// Return the developer provider name which you choose while setting up the
// identity pool in the Amazon Cognito Console

- (BOOL)authenticatedWithProvider {
    return [self.logins objectForKey:self.providerName] != nil;
}


// If the app has a valid identityId return it, otherwise get a valid
// identityId from your backend.

- (AWSTask *)getIdentityId {
    // already cached the identity id, return it
    if (self.identityId) {
        return [AWSTask taskWithResult:nil];
    }
    // not authenticated with our developer provider
    else if (![self authenticatedWithProvider]) {
        return [super getIdentityId];
    }
    // authenticated with our developer provider, use refresh logic to get id/token pair
    else {
        return [[AWSTask taskWithResult:nil] continueWithBlock:^id(AWSTask *task) {
            if (!self.identityId) {
                return [self refresh];
            }
            return [AWSTask taskWithResult:self.identityId];
        }];
    }

}


// Use the refresh method to communicate with your backend to get an
// identityId and token.

- (AWSTask *)refresh {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if (![self authenticatedWithProvider]) {
        return [super getIdentityId];
    }else{
        NSDictionary *post = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              [defaults objectForKey:@"username"], @"username",
                              [defaults objectForKey:@"password"], @"password",
                              nil];
        NSError *error;
        NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:post options:0 error:&error];
        NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
        [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"SOMELOGINURL"]];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        [request setHTTPBody:postData];
        NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
        [[session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
            NSDictionary *newJSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                                    options:0
                                                                      error:&error];
            if(!newJSON){
            NSLog(@"Failure in refresh: %@",newJSON);
            }else{
            NSLog(@"The IdentityID in the refresh method: %@",[newJSON objectForKey:@"IdentityId" ]);
            NSLog(@"The token in the refresh method: %@",[newJSON objectForKey:@"Token" ]);
            self.identityId = [newJSON objectForKey:@"IdentityId" ];
            self.token = [newJSON objectForKey:@"Token" ];
            }
        }] resume];

        return [AWSTask taskWithResult:self.identityId];
    }
    return [AWSTask taskWithResult:self.identityId];
}


@end
```

Some Questions I had:

1. Is the DeveloperAuthenticationClient necessary to solve my problems? I saw the sample app using them but I found them too confusing.
2. Should I be using my ProviderName or should I be using "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com"
3. I sometimes face a timeout error and found out that it could be the fact that my implementation of login (using API Gateway and a lambda method) could have some cold-start issues. The way I solved this is by increasing the timeout time to 20 seconds. Is this the correct way to solve this?
4. I saw that in the sample app they use GetToken and Login as two separate things. I thought it would be easier if my login could also serve as my GetToken. Is this appropriate?
5. Finally, please address any problems that you see with my code if time permits.

Error:

> [Error] AWSCredentialsProvider.m line:527 |
>   __40-[AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider refresh]_block_invoke352 | Unable to refresh. Error is [Error
>   Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSCognitoCredentialsProviderErrorDomain Code=1
>   "identityId shouldn't be nil"
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=identityId shouldn't be nil}]

(I also found out the error above is related to the fact that self.identityId didn't get set because the request was in a block and other parts executed first and the solution is:

```
- (AWSTask *)refresh {
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if (![self authenticatedWithProvider]) {
    return [super getIdentityId];
}else{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *string = [defaults objectForKey:@"IdentityId"];
    self.identityId = string;
    return [AWSTask taskWithResult:[defaults objectForKey:@"IdentityId"]];
}
NSString *string = [defaults objectForKey:@"IdentityId"];
return [AWSTask taskWithResult:[defaults objectForKey:@"IdentityId"]];
}
```

But I believe that this isn't the correct implementation. )

I believe my code was working at a certain point but stopped working after I upgraded to the new SDK. However, it might just be the fact that I hadn't noticed the error initially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answers to your questions:

1. Yes you need to have some entity(client) which communicates with your backend system.
2. You are using cognito-identity.amazonaws.com in the logins map, but using the IdentityProvider pattern for refresh. This is why the first authentication succeeds but attempts to refresh fail. The logic in your refresh will never fire. Please look at our [end to end sample](https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx3E3NJURV1LNV1/Integrating-Amazon-Cognito-using-developer-authenticated-identities-An-end-to-en) on how to implement developer authenticated identities.
3. From my limited knowledge yes this is one way, but you may face performance issues. Please contact AWS Lambda via their forums for more guidance on this.
4. We highly recommend following the flow in the sample. The getToken doesn't need your authentication credentials if you have established trust, whereas login will always need the authentication credentials, so better not to mix these.

Thanks..